# Where is WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__ local group in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2016, winrm, window-server-2012

With Windows Server 2012 R2 I can use the group *WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__* to enable remote PowerShell execution via `-CimSession` for non-admin users. However, the group is missing on my Windows Server 2016 machines and I do not see any replacement for it except the *Remote Management Users* group. However it seems to me that it grants wider permissions than *WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__*.

Where is the *WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__* group in Windows Server 2016?

Comment: `Get-LocalGroup` or `Get-ADGroup` should show it although according to the [Active Directory default security groups by operating system version](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/active-directory-security-groups#bkmk-groupstable) table, `WinRMRemoteWMIUsers_` group does not seem to be present in _Windows Server 2016_

Comment: @JosefZ no, `Get-LocalGroup` does not show *WinRMRemoteWMIUsers_*.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384295(v=vs.85).aspx suggests the group is created during WinRM configuration.  Can you try `winrm quickconfig` to see if it recreates what you need?  If it does, I'll write up a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[KB3118385](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3118385/svchost-exe-uses-excessive-cpu-resources-on-a-single-core-windows-serv) seems to suggest that you can manually create it. Have you tried doing that?

EDIT: 
As Matthew stated below, here are the commands. Thanks Matthew!

```
net localgroup WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__
```

And if that fails:

```
net localgroup /add WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__
```

Comment: It does not seem to be the same problem as KB3118385 because the computer is not a domain controller and the group has to be local, that's not a domain group.

Comment: I understand. I was only suggesting that since KB3118385 implies that it can be manually created, that maybe it can be manually created on Server 2016 as well.

Comment: This appears correct based on Windows test collateral. While I've worked near this team, this is not an "official" statement of support by the owners.   Try `net localgroup WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__` or if that fails, `net localgroup /add WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__`  If this works, Mike can add these steps to his answer and claim the bounty.  He needs/deserves the bounty more than I do. :)   (Welcome to Server Fault, Mike!)

Comment: Thank you! Creating the group manually works. I don't understand why the group is missing in Windows Server 2016.